# why my 'time' class has not 'tzset' attribute

Tags: python, syntax

my code:

```
import time
print hasattr(time.tzset)#error
```

and why someone do this like next:

```
if hasattr(time, 'tzset'):
            # Move the time zone info into os.environ. See ticket #2315 for why
            # we don't do this unconditionally (breaks Windows).
            os.environ['TZ'] = self.TIME_ZONE
            time.tzset()
```

i can't understand.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?highlight=tzset#time.tzset) for `tzset`: they clearly say

> Availability: Unix.

so you would have it in, say, MacOSX, Solaris, or Linux, but not on Windows.

Also: there is no such thing as "your time class", despite your Q's title: the `time` you're trying to use is a *module*, **not** a *class*.

And finally, as @Daniel says, your first use of `hasattr` is totally wrong (the second one, which you don't understand, is correct).

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `hasattr` is wrong. The correct syntax is shown in your second snippet.

`hasattr` takes two arguments - an object, and a string represent the attribute you want to check for. The way you've done it, Python will try to evaluate `time.tzset` first, before passing it to `hasattr` - thus causing the very error you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have a local module that is shadowing the stock `time` module, you're using a version of Python older than 2.3, or you're running Python on Windows.